# creating index on nvarchar(max) column

Tags: sql-server-2012, query-performance, nvarchar

I have table contains three columns. If I select `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column in my select statement, I see poor performance. Is it possible to create index on a `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column?.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
     id primary key,
     product VARCHAR(50),
     Title NVARCHAR(max)
)

INSERTING MILLIONS OF RECORDS....

SELECT product, Title 
FROM TEST
```

The table contains million of records. How can I create an index for this column? Is it really improve performance of my select statement? Or is there any other method to improve this?

Comment: You can't index an `nvarchar(MAX)` column. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql), "columns that are of the large object (LOB) data types ntext, text, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml, or image cannot be specified as key columns for an index". An index won't typically improve performance of a query without a `WHERE` or `JOIN` clause.

Comment: The **max size** for an index entry in SQL Server is **900 bytes** - and that's the **possible** size of a variable length column - so for `NVARCHAR`, the max would be a `NVARCHAR(450)` column. Anything bigger **CANNOT** be indexed.

Comment: Thanks.shall we use include(index) like below? is it correct and useful?
create index ix_test on test(id)include(title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can index an NVARCHAR(MAX) with a "[Full-Text Search index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017)".

As an aside, the SQL in your post doesn't include a `WHERE` or a `JOIN`, so I'm pretty sure that an index won't improve the `SELECT` performance of all the titles. It will *decrease* the speed of inserts, of course, because the inserts will be slower if you add an additional index.

Answer (score 2):

When this question was posted for SQL Server 2012 it was true that 900 bytes was the limit for any type of index key (both clustered and non clustered) this has changed in later versions of SQL Server.

**Up to SQL Server 2014**

Any type of index key can be maximum 900 bytes.

So maximum nvarchar should be something like `nvarchar(448)`

**SQL Server 2016 and above**

Clustered index key: 900 bytes
Non clustered index keys: 1700 bytes

So maximum nvarchar should be something like `nvarchar(848)`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016